# AlarmManager и режим сна

Tags: android, java

Пытаюсь разобраться с *AlarmManager* и режимом сна. И оказалось что я слабо представляю что такое этот режим сна. Я создал два будильника: один с типом `ELAPSED_REALTIME` и с типом `ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP`.

```
manager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+60000*5, pendingIntent);
manager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+60000*5, pendingIntent);
```

`pendingIntent` - просто запускает службу, которая пишет в `LogCat`.
разумеется запускал их по отдельности и разницу в них не увидел - обе команды привели к одинаковым действиям. Скажите в чём разница между этими режимами?

Comment: А попробуйте таймер выставить на 1 час и оставить на ночь. Только не вместе, что бы  не мешали. (кстати, следите за программами, некоторые мешают переходить в режим сна).
Один с таймеров будет исправно срабатывать, а второй - нет.

Режим сна - это такой режим, когда телефон понимает, что его не трогают, работы нет и можно "поспать").

Comment: я понимаю что режим сна пытается отключить процессор во время бездействия. думаете 5 минут не хватало для засыпания?
Как я теперь понимаю, если аппарат находится в режиме сна, то он в принципе должен игнорировать будильник который имеет метку ELAPSED_REALTIME ?

Comment: я также думаю, что он должен игнорировать.

Comment: Доки читать не пробовали? 
int ELAPSED_REALTIME:Alarm time in SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()(time since boot, including sleep).
int ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP :Alarm time in SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() (time since boot, including sleep), which will wake up the device when it goes off.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html